# Cannot print text from a line edit to a label in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

I have recently started developing in Qt for C++ because I wanted to go more cross-platform and develop applications with a gui. I am trying to get the text from a lineEdit which the user enters, presses a button and that button toggles the display to show that same text in a label. Its worth noting that I am developing in QT Creator because I don't have access to my windows desktop right now. 
The mainWindow.hpp file is practically default but I have just added the 'public slots' to link the objects together.

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void setText();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

The main.cpp hasn't changed at all.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The mainWindow.cpp is probably the most important file and this is what I think has the issue.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->textBtn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(setText()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::setText()
{
    QString temp;
    ui->inputText->textChanged(temp);
    ui->displayLabel->setText(temp);

}
```

I have no idea whats going wrong. The compiler can build the program correctly but if I press the button, nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong in terms of the setText() function or is it the signals and slot connection?

Comment: change `connect(ui->textBtn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(setText()));` to `connect(ui->textBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::setText);` and `QString temp; ui->inputText->textChanged(temp);` to `QString temp = ui->inputText->text();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the setText function to

```
void MainWindow::setText()
{
    QString temp = ui->inputText->text();
    ui->displayLabel->setText(temp);    
}
```